# How to get the row with two or more specific condition?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

ApplicantTbl

```
id | name          |
--------------------
 1 | John Doe      |
 2 | Maria Ozawa   |
 3 | Catriona Gray |
--------------------
```

EnrollmentRequestContentTbl

```
id |  applicant_id | payment_status  |   enrollment_status   |
--------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |       1       |     pending     |        null           |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

My goal is to get all the applicants including the applicant_id 1 `if`:

1. The `payment_status` on `enrollmentRequestContentTbl` is **paid**
2. The `payment_status` on `enrollmentRequestContentTbl` is **unpaid** and the `enrollment_status` is `back_out` or `declined`

The rest posible condition will be ignored and will not be able to get from my query.

*The above table will ignore the applicant 1 since the `payment_status` is `pending`.*

If the EnrollmentRequestContentTbl will look like this

```
 id |  applicant_id | payment_status  |   enrollment_status   |
 --------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |       1        |     paid        |        null           |
 --------------------------------------------------------------
```

or this. Since the `paymet_status` is **unpaid** `enrollment_status` must be **back_out** or **declined**

```
 id |  applicant_id | payment_status  |   enrollment_status   |
 --------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |       1        |     unpaid      |        back_out       |
 --------------------------------------------------------------
```

-

```
 id |  applicant_id | payment_status  |   enrollment_status   |
 --------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |       1        |     unpaid      |        declined       |
 --------------------------------------------------------------
```

*The applicant 1 will be included to my query and show on my list.*

-
**ApplicantModel**

```
public function enrollmentRequestContent()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\EnrollmentRequestContent');
}
```

**EnrollmentRequestContentModel**

```
public function applicant()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Applicant')
}
```

So far this is what I've tried.

**Controller**

```
public function getApplicant()
{
    $applicants = Applicant::orWhereDoesntHave('enrollmentRequestContent', function($q){
        $q->where('payment_status', '!=', 'paid')
            ->where(function($qq) {
                $qq->where('payment_status', '!=', 'unpaid')
                        ->whereIn('enrollment_status', ['declined', 'back_out']);
            });
    })->get();   

    return $applicants;
}
```

Im using laravel eloquent query.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually close. You just have to change the logic, this is what I've done:

First, get all the applicants that doesn't exist in the `pivot table` by using `whereDoesntHave`.

Next is get all applicants that exist in the `pivot table` **only if** its status is 'paid' (by using `orWhereHas`) **or** its status is 'unpaid' but its enrollment status should either 'back_out' or 'declined' (by using `orWhereHas` with `whereIn`).

```
$data = Applicant::whereDoesntHave('enrollmentRequestContents')
    ->orWhereHas('enrollmentRequestContents', function($q1){
        $q1->where('payment_status', 'paid');
    })
    ->orWhereHas('enrollmentRequestContents', function($q2){
        $q2->where('payment_status', 'unpaid')
           ->whereIn('enrollment_status', ['back_out', 'declined']);
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code will satisfy your conditions.

```
public function getApplicant()
{
      $applicants = Applicant::with(['enrollmentRequestContent'])
                ->whereHas('enrollmentRequestContent', function($query){
                    $query->where(function($q){
                        $q->whereIn('payment_status', ['declined', 'back_out'])
                         ->where('payment_status', '!=','unpaid');
                    });
                    $query->orWhere('payment_status', '!=', 'paid');
                })

     return $applicants;
}
```

Comment: I changed the `payment_status` as **pending** and must be not belong to the query. But in your answer it showed. Also, My goal is to get all the applicant in **applicanttbl** but in your answer it show only the applicat that has `enrollmentRequestContent`.